# I have a light that I want to order new optics for. Any one know how to find manufacturer information or spec sheets?

Tags: led, pcb

[image: LED circuit board]

A friend showed me LEDsupply.com where you can order new lenses and possibly LED replacements. However, I have not been able to find enough information about this led or circuit board to move forward. I'm hoping someone knows a reliable site or way to conduct this type of backward search.

Comment: Nothing on this board (at least the side shown) that could help.

Comment: I think what matters is clearly understanding what do you want to achieve with the optics. You can't just look at an LED and some "stuff" and magically "know" what would be required. I don't even know what I'm looking at. What does it do?

Comment: Go back to where you bought it from and ask them. Your question is undoubtedly off-topic on EE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look for a lenses for the  [Cree Xlamp XPE](http://www.cree.com/led-components/media/documents/XLampXPE.pdf) on that board.

[LEDiL](http://www.ledil.com/) is probably your best bet.  They have 266 for the XPE here: [LedIL Product Search](http://www.ledil.com/products?ds=1&mn=&ld=21&md=&xd=&mh=&xh=&mt=&mf=&xf=&sf=&ty=&fm=&sm=&cn=&vc=&io=&tro=&trt=0&tpo=&tpt=0&tr=&tp=&fr=&st=0&pg=0&lo=&ol=0&of=0&od=0&oh=0)

There are many stick-on tape or glue down lenses that will work on that board.

You can go to any major electronics distributor and they will have LEDiL and many others.   The category is usually optics=>Lenses e.g. [Digikey,  Optoelectronics > Optics - Lenses](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/optoelectronics/optics-lenses/112)

As far as replacing the LED itself, there are thousands of possibilities. Cree's new XP-3G would be a good choice.  It has 81% Wall Watt efficiency and has the same PCB footprint. Or an OSRAM Olsen SSL has a smaller footprint but will often fit in an Xlamp footprint.  The Olsen SSL come with 80°, 120°, or 150° optics and are inexpensive.